# Automatically get cluster credentials when activating gcloud configuration

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud

Working in GCP with several kubernetes clusters, I would like to automatically get cluster credentials when switching gcloud configurations.

I have created several configurations for gcloud with `gcloud config configurations create [config-name]` and I have set what I need, specifically `gcloud config set container/cluster [cluster-name]`.

When I switch configurations with `gcloud config configurations activate [config-name]`, everything goes ok, except I do not get the credentials for the cluster I have configured for that configuration. Instead I need to run `gcloud container clusters get-credentials [cluster-name]`.

Is there any way to automatically get credentials for a cluster when activating a gcloud configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I think not.

`gcloud` and `kubectl` are distinct tools and each maintains its own configuration.

`gcloud container custers get-credentials` is a bridging helper that configures `kubectl` configuration (conventionally located in `~/.kube/config` file) with a `gcloud` auth helper to facilitate accessing Kubernetes Engine clusters. But, otherwise the 2 tools are unrelated.

Have a look at this post I wrote that covers using different configurations with `kubectl`. It's not exactly what you want but I hope it will be useful:

https://medium.com/google-cloud/context-light-gcloud-and-kubectl-89185d38ce82

Comment: Thanks, that is interesting! I will probably try to mix that info with a script to do achieve both things with one command.

Comment: You can use aliases too. Set `alias mycluster="gcloud container clusters get-credentials [CLUSTER_NAME]"` in a shell script and  set `source ~/.somedir/aliases.sh` in your shell profiles. Then just typing `mycluster` you'll get your cluster credentials.